# how to copy virtual machine for use in vmware

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have my virtual machines of Vmware 15 in following folder 
E:\installed software\vmware\virtual machines

I have downloaded a cloudera virtual machine for hadopp in folder
E:\studies\programming lab assignments\cloud computing\cloudera-vmware

I open vmware 15 workstation I don't see an option to import this virtual machine of cloudera, how do I do this.
I am using Windows 8.1 Is there any setting to import virtual machine?

Comment: What format is your download in? Did you read the official documentation for the product?

Comment: it is vmdk format.

Comment: If you only have a vmdk file you likely need to create a new virtual machine and assign it as the hard disk during creation.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way:

1. Right click on "File" and select "New Virtual Machine".
   Select "I will install the operating system later, create a virtual blank hard drive" and click "Next".
2. After creating the virtual machine, right click on the virtual machine and select "Settings".
3. Select "Hard Disk" and click "Remove".
4. Click "Add", select "Use existing virtual disk", and select the path to our vmdk file.
5. Click to power on the virtual machine, you can open the virtual machine, use the software contained in the vmdk file system.